# Method to capture the whole Screen from a Floating Window Application

Tags: java, android, widget, floating, screen-capture

I'm trying to do implement a floating widget button(like the Facebook Messenger) which is displayed over the other app. The button should be able to interfere with the displayed view of the other app and capture the whole smartphone screen underneath.

The floating button is already implemented and works fine on every app. Getting the root view and printing out the bitmap of this floating view will just return the floating button image. I think the floating window cant detect the view of the apps underneath.

One possible solution could be to start the other application as a separate activity and get its view, but I am not sure how to do that. Maybe there is some easier way to achieve this?

```
//Creating the floating window and set its Layout parameters

mFloatViewLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
mFloatViewLayoutParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
mFloatViewLayoutParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FORMAT_CHANGED;

mFloatViewLayoutParams.type = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O
                ? WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
                : WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_BASE_APPLICATION;
mFloatViewLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.START;
mFloatViewLayoutParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
mFloatViewLayoutParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

// adding the floatview to the WindowManager
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
mFloatView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.float_view_layout, null);
mWindowManager.addView(mFloatView, mFloatViewLayoutParams);

...
// some clickListener to start the screenshot
ImageButton imageButton = mFloatView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // here I want to get the view of the whole screen to 
                        screenshot it
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

What I don't want: I don't want to screenshot the view of my main activity which starts the floating button.

I am really out of ideas about how to handle this challenge. Hopefully, someone has a guess!

Cheers!

Comment: Use the media projection APIs, available on Android 5.0+.

Comment: @CommonsWare This might be what I'm searching for. Thanks! Do you know if other apps can detect if this AP gets used?

Comment: I do not know if they can detect it. They can definitely block it, using `FLAG_SECURE`.